# Bootstrap menu links do not work when collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to define a menu that I've got fixed to the top of my webpage.  The problem is that the links work exactly how I want, until they collapse into a dropdown menu.  Once collapsed, they work only sometimes.  I can't find any errors in the the console to help guide me as to why they don't work most of the time.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

-To those who responded already, Thanks!  Sorry it was a poorly made example.  I've stripped out more of it, and this example should run.  I still have the same problem.  I can't figure out why those link's won't work.

```js
    function loadMenuItem (name) {
     var newHTML;
     switch(name){
      case 'home':
       newHTML = "<p>Some home page</p>";
       break;
      case 'learn':
       newHTML = "<p>Some learn page</p>";
       break;
      case 'blog':
       newHTML = "<p>Some blog page</p>";
       break;
      case 'forum':
       newHTML = "<p>Some forum page</p>";
       break;
      case 'tools':
       newHTML = "<p>Some tools page</p>";
       break;
     }
     document.getElementById("main-content").innerHTML = newHTML;
    }
    
    $(function () {
    $("#navbarToggle").blur(function (event) {
     var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
     if(screenWidth < 768) {
      $("#collapsable-nav").collapse('hide');
     }
    });
   });
   $(".nav a").on("click", function(){
      $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).parent().addClass("active");
   });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Test Page</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>

  
 <body>
  <header>
   <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse nav-justified" >
    <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
           
      
      <button id="navbarToggle" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
     </div>
     
     <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="active"><a href="#" onclick="loadMenuItem('home');">HOME</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" onclick="loadMenuItem('blog');">BLOG</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" onclick="loadMenuItem('forum');">FORUM</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" onclick="loadMenuItem('learn');">LEARN</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" onclick="loadMenuItem('tools');">TOOLS</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </nav>
  </header>
  
  <!-- The main body of the page is here.  AJAX is used to dynamically change which page is visible. -->
  <div id="main-content" class="container"></div>


  
   
   <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe some element is overlapping the menu links..

Comment: Maybe you can start by minimizing this code. There is a lot of custom JS that's not standard Bootstrap.

Comment: I'd start by creating a [mcve] that actually works. See [ask] for help.